# Best Practice: When should I put requireJs into a separate file?

Tags: magento2, requirejs

This is somewhat silly but I keep encountering extensions who vary on putting requireJS into a separate file vs inlining it. I usually decouple things where possible. Is it fair to say the JS should be separated when it is not dependent upon the component and/or base it upon chances of the JS being reused for other components?